# Acessar de aplicativo imagens da web

Tags: android, web-service

Sou iniciante em desenvolvimento de aplicativo android; tenho a seguinte dúvida: se quero fazer um aplicativo em que as imagens utilizadas não constam dentro do projeto, mas na web, qual a melhor forma de fazer essa conexão. Seria penas acessando pela classe URL ou utilizando o WebService?

Answer (score 4):

Você pode criar um `AsyncTask` para carregar as imagens de maneira assíncrona. Veja os códigos abaixo de como fazer:

```
private class FetchImageTask extends AsyncTask<String, Integer, Bitmap> {
    @Override
    protected Bitmap doInBackground(String... arg0) {
        Bitmap b = null;
        try {
            b = BitmapFactory.decodeStream((InputStream) new URL(arg0[0]).getContent());
        }
        catch (MalformedURLException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
        catch (IOException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
        return b;
    }
}
```

E para implementar utilize este código:

```
new FetchImageTask() {
        @Override
        protected void onPostExecute(Bitmap result) {
            if (result != null) {
                image.setImageBitmap(result);
            }
        }
    }.execute("IMAGE_URL");
```

**EDIT**

[Exemplo no GitHub](https://github.com/giancarloandroid/MeuAprendizado/tree/master/ProjetosExemplo/DownloadImage)

Comment: Mas isso é recomendável? Trata-se de um aplicativo de venda de acessórios de carro. O que seria melhor, assim ou utilizando a conexão cliente/servidor?

Comment: O que recomendaria você fazer é salvar as imagens em um servidor, seja Apache, IIS, Wildfly ou outro que você preferir. Salvar o caminho da imagem no banco de dados SQLite no Android, como, por exemplo, `IP_SERVIDOR:8080/aplicacao/imagens_carros/corcel.jpg` para visualizar a imagem do carro Corcel, consultando no banco SQLite essa URL e passando a URL da imagem onde está escrito `IMAGE_URL` do exemplo que lhe dei. Qualquer dúvida só chamar.

Comment: Valeu, Giancarlo... vou tentar por aí!

Comment: Giancarlo, você indicaria algum vídeo de alguém utilizando esse processo?

Comment: Pior que não tenho, posso criar uma página e fazer um tutorial assim que tiver tempo, mas não é díficil de criar. Você baixa o Apache e instala na máquina, cria um diretório da aplicacao, e dentro desse diretório a pasta imagens onde ficam as imagens dos carros. Ai no Android realiza a solicitação do caminho URL da imagem. Trouxe esse link para lhe ajudar a rodar um servidor Apache na máquina caso tenha Windows, espero que ajude: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=1326zewpdqI, qualquer dúvida só pedir.

Comment: Giancarlo, pesquisei muito mas não dirimir essas dúvidas: Como salvar imagens no Apache ou no Engix; Como salvar o caminho no banco de dados SQLIte; Qual a importância o JSON nesse caso? Desculpa é que apesar de estudar muito esse assunto, vejo ele muito fragmentado. Decidir usar a lib Fresco e o servidor Engix, mas não estou entendendo o processo de acesso ao servidor.

Comment: Criei um repositório no Github e irei fazer o exemplo mostrando como funciona assim que tiver tempo, ainda essa semana. Ai edito minha postagem com o exemplo aqui (;

Comment: Certo... valeW!

Comment: Amigo, alterei o post, coloquei um link que leva a um dos meus diretórios no GitHub com um pequeno projeto exemplo que fiz utilizando Android e um servidor Apache carregando uma imagem de um leão. Tem instruções de como instalar e configurar o Apache que acredito que era o que você queria, assim você consegue montar um webservice legal para o seu projeto. Tem umas referência para lhe ajudar qualquer coisa.

Comment: Não pude olhar antes, mas vou dá uma olhada e qualquer coisa peço tua ajuda. Certo? Obrigado.

Comment: Seu projeto não pode ser baixado, para teste? Achei muito difícil entender pelo GitHub.

Comment: Sim, mas tem que configurar o ambiente de desenvolvimento, coloquei lá como instalar, bem facinho.

Comment: Abri seu projeto, mas não funcionou... sua imagem não abre.

Comment: Funciona porque testei aqui antes de lhe passar o link.

Answer (score 3):

Você pode resolver isso só em uma linha utilizando a lib de imagem, pode ser tanto a Picasso, Glide, Universal Image Loader.Exemplo com a Picasso:

```
Picasso.with(context).load("http://i.imgur.com/DvpvklR.png").into(imageView);
```

Explicando. primeiro você passa o contexto de sua Class, segundo a Url da Image e por ultimo o teu ImageView. É muito simples. 
Link da lib: http://square.github.io/picasso/

Comment: Valeu, Alessandro... vou estudar essa opção também.

Comment: Valeu, não conhecia sobre o Picasso.

Comment: Mas o fato de usar essa lib, não quer dizer que não precise de um servidor; não é isso?

Comment: você pode e tem que usar um servidor sim, porque sem o servidor suas imagens vão ficar estáticas e já com o servidor você vai ter maior controle, pesquise sobre comunicação de webservice com android e JSON. Aí sim você usuária a lib para pegar essa informação do servidor que vai ser passada em um JSON e assim jogar no load da lib.

Comment: Beleza, Alessandro!

Answer (score 1):

Quando preciso acessar algum conteúdo da web com o android utilizo a biblioteca Volley, ela é bem simples de usar. Aqui tem um link para um exemplo que faz o request de uma imagem:

https://developer.android.com/training/volley/request.html#request-image

**Edit**- Exemplo de uso:

Primeiro você adiciona o .jar da biblioteca no seu projeto. Depois você pode realizar o request de forma bem simples: basta criar uma instancia de StringRequest (para texto), no contrutor você pode explicar o método que precisa (POST ou GET), em seguida a URL (no meu exemplo a url está em RequestContract.XMLQuestionarioContract.XML_QUESITIONARIO_URL) e por ultimo só precisa implementar o listener, no onResponse o retorno estará no parâmetro do método. Por ultimo só precisa adicionar a requisição em uma fila.

```
 private void requestQuestionario(){
    String tag_string_req = "req_questionario"; //tag para cancelar o request

    pDialog.setMessage("Carregando Questionário...");
    showDialog();

    StringRequest stringRequest = new StringRequest(Request.Method.GET,
            RequestContract.XMLQuestionarioContract.XML_QUESITIONARIO_URL, new Response.Listener<String>() {

        @Override
        public void onResponse(String s) {
            Log.d(TAG, "Response = " + s);

            //TODO -- Tratar Response
            InputStream xml = new ByteArrayInputStream(s.getBytes());
            try {
                HashMap questionario = XmlParser.parse(xml);
                List<Questao> questoes = (List) questionario.get("questoes");
                List<Alternativa> alternativas = (List) questionario.get("alternativas");
                List<Codigo> codigos = (List) questionario.get("codigos");

                DataBaseHelper db = new DataBaseHelper(getApplicationContext());

                db.insertQuestoes(questoes);
                db.insertAlternativas(alternativas);
                db.insertCodigos(codigos);

            } catch (XmlPullParserException e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            } catch (IOException e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            } catch (SQLException e){
                e.printStackTrace();
            }

            hideDialog();
        }
    }, new Response.ErrorListener() {
        @Override
        public void onErrorResponse(VolleyError volleyError) {
            //TODO -- Tratar erro
            Log.e(TAG, "Erro no request");
            hideDialog();
        }
    });

    requestQueue = RequestManager.getInstance(this).getRequestQueue();

    stringRequest.setTag(tag_string_req);
    requestQueue.add(stringRequest);
}
```

Nesse exemplo utilizo o conteúdo da String 's' do onResponse(String s) para fazer o parsing de um XML, mas poderia ser uma String qualquer ou até mesmo um Json.

Para a RequestQueue a Documentação da Google recomenda utilizar um Singleton, mas pode ser instanciado da seguinte forma:

```
RequestQueue queue = Volley.newRequestQueue(this);
```

Para fazer a requisição de uma imagem na documentação da google utiliza esse exemplo:

```
ImageView mImageView;
String url = "http://i.imgur.com/7spzG.png";
mImageView = (ImageView) findViewById(R.id.myImage);
...

// Retrieves an image specified by the URL, displays it in the UI.
ImageRequest request = new ImageRequest(url,
   new Response.Listener<Bitmap>() {
       @Override
       public void onResponse(Bitmap bitmap) {
           mImageView.setImageBitmap(bitmap);
       }
   }, 0, 0, null,
   new Response.ErrorListener() {
       public void onErrorResponse(VolleyError error) {
           mImageView.setImageResource(R.drawable.image_load_error);
       }
   });
  // Access the RequestQueue through your singleton class.
  MySingleton.getInstance(this).addToRequestQueue(request);
```

O StringRequest foi substituido por um ImageRequest e o parâmetro do onResponse por um BitMap

Comment: Podeira dar um breve resumo de como que utiliza essa bibliboteca? Sem isso sua resposta fica muito simplória.